# AngularJS and google cloud endpoint: walk through needed

Tags: angularjs, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm new to AngularJS but I really like the way AngularJS works so I want to deployed it as client side for my Google cloud endpoint backend. Then I immediately get two problems:

1, Where to put the **myCallback**, so it's able to work into the ANgularJs controller?

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=myCallback"></script>
```

2, How I'm able to do the oauth2? and how the controller knows if the user authorized?

```
gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: myCLIENT_ID,
      scope: mySCOPES,.....
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For loading Google Javascript Library with AngularJs, the callback function passed to onLoad of Google Javascript Library is the function that bootstrap AngularJS, like this:

This goes to the final of html file:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=startApp">
```

Then, in `<head>` section you bootstrap angular like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

function startApp() {

    var ROOT = 'http://<yourapi>.appspot.com/_ah/api';
    gapi.client.load('myapifromgoogleendpoint', 'version1', function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ["myModule"]);
    }, ROOT);
}

</script>
```

**As described by Kenji, you also need to remove ng-app directive from your html.**

Comment: To someone trying above, you have to remove ng-app, e.g. <html ng-app="myModule">  It's one of the "manual bootstrap" techniques, and it doesn't work when ng-app is set.

Comment: I think Kenji's comment should be included in the answer; it could save much time to people (angular beginners in particular)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the callback - In order to access an Angular controller you need to use an injector (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.$injector)

Simply create a global callback function, and then get reference to the controller from it like this:

```
window.callbackFunction() {
  injector = angular.element(document.getElementById('YourController')).injector()
  injector.invoke(function ($rootScope, $compile, $document) {
    $rootScope.variable = "stuff you want to inject";
  })
}
```

In this example I'm injecting the data to the rootScope, but this will also work for a specific controller scope (just inject $scope instead)

Can't help with the second question as I'm not familiar with gapi, though making auth2 calls from angularjs is quite straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have details on how to use angularjs with google endpoints:

https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/angularjs-cloud-endpoints-recipe-for-building-modern-web-applications?hl=es