# What's the correct way to indicate to your scope that your google apis have loaded?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-app-engine

This is a pretty newbie question I'm afraid.  I've been reading through a lot of tutorials about using app engine, but unfortunately not a lot of them use AngularJS.

I am trying to use an app engine api endpoint and connect into it with a javascript client.  When I load my endpoint using

```
function informAngularOfGAPIReady() {
     // SCOPE IS NOT DEFINED HERE
     $scope.$apply(function() {
         $scope.google_backend_ready = true;
     });
}

// This function is the callback for when the Google apis are ready.
function init() {
    gapi.client.load('helloworld', 'v1', informAngularOfGAPIReady, '/_ah/api');
}
```

I find that $scope is undefined for informAngularOfGAPIReady.

On the tutorial by google (https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/angularjs-cloud-endpoints-recipe-for-building-modern-web-applications), in tip #3 (at the very bottom of the page) they recommend using this approach, but i don't understand how $scope can be defined.

I know that you can use the document object to search for a view which you can then extract the scope from, but this doesn't seem like a very clean approach.  Some examples I saw just passed null for the load callback but this doesn't make a lot of sense because you can't have your UI reflect that it's not ready for requests yet.

How do people usually do this?  I would think this is a problem for anyone using app engine to host apis.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample code in the tutorial is meant to be placed in a controller (ie. inside of an Angular app). They demonstrate it declared in the view as:

```
<div ng-controller="GuestbookCtrl" class="container" ng-show="is_backend_ready">
…. guestbook UI...
</div>
```

Your controller code might look something like:

```
.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.informAngularOfGAPIReady = function() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.google_backend_ready = true;
        });
    }

    $scope.init = function() {
        gapi.client.load('helloworld', 'v1', $scope.informAngularOfGAPIReady, '/_ah/api');
    }
});
```

... where the scope is injected into the controller and your callback functions is defined on it. You still do need to use `$apply` since it will be fired from outside of the Angular framework.

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes a lot of sense!

Comment: As an aside, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15905755/angularjs-and-google-cloud-endpoint-walk-through-needed was someone having a similar issue.  They just queried for the root scope which also works.